# Getting error when using the GetContent function of SwfTreeView in Windows10 while same code is passing in Windows7

Tags: node-stringprep

We have a UFT code running fine in Windows 7 but when we run the same code in Windows10 it is giving below error

> Unspecified error
>
> Function file Path: ****
>
> Line (303): " nodesString = tree.GetContent".

Actually we are passing an object of the SwfTreeView to a function call where it is trying to retreive entire content of the tree so that it can then find the first node of the tree.. code is as below:

```
Set folderTree = SwfWindow("Network Device Explorer").SwfObject("Folders").SwfTreeView("allFoldersTree")
.......
folderFound = ShowTreeNode(folderTree, folderPane, folderName, "")
.......
rootNode = findRootNode(treeViewObject, parentText)

inside the **findRootNode function** we have a code to get contents of the tree, it is failng there...
i.e. as below

nodesString = tree.GetContent
```

FAILING ONLY WHEN WE RUN ON WINDOWS 10 MCHINE WHILE PASSIN ON WINDOWS7 MACHINES.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Akash

Actually we are passing an object of the SwfTreeView to a function call where it is trying to retreive entire content of the tree so that it can then find the first node of the tree....